# How to S3 cmd for CSS Static Website Hosting?

Tags: html, css, amazon-s3

I am having an issue linking main.css with my index.html file on aws s3. I've attempted to s3cmd but I keep running into this error...

`chrisscott@ChristophersMBP ~ % s3cmd put -m Documents/Code/html+css/api-search/css/main.css s3://iniquityscure.org/main.css`

```
/usr/local/bin/s3cmd:308: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if response["status"] is 200:
/usr/local/bin/s3cmd:310: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  elif response["status"] is 204:
Usage: s3cmd [options] COMMAND [parameters]

s3cmd: error: option -m: invalid MIME-Type format: 'Documents/Code/html+css/api-search/css/main.css'
```

Comment: what version of python are you using? seems you are getting 2 unrelated errors

Comment: Python 2.7.16 I just attempted it with python3 which gave me a result with a configuration error apposed to a syntax... ` ERROR: /Users/chrisscott/.s3cfg: None
ERROR: Configuration file not available.
ERROR: Consider using --configure parameter to create one. `

Comment: got it! I ended up syncing the bucket with *My_Path* to change the configuration. thank you so much.

Comment: Side-note: These days, it is recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

Comment: how can you change modifications with the aws cli?

Answer (score 0):

I think two options:

- You can try without "-m" and s3cmd set auto mime type.
- You can set correct mime type: -m "text/css".

Best regards